# Algorithm for computing the smallest subset of nodes to remove from a graph to make it a tree

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

I have encountered an interesting problem that I couldn't find any references to solve:

> Determine the smallest subset of nodes that
>   need to be removed from an undirected graph to make it a tree.

Obviously when a node is removed, the edges connecting to it are also removed.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: To make it a forest instead of a tree, your problem is the [feedback vertex set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set). Is this what you need, or do you specifically want the remaining induced subgraph to be a tree?

Comment: To make it a tree (i.e connected and acyclic) is sometimes studied under the name Tree Deletion Set. It is NP-hard, much harder to approximate than Feedback Vertex Set, but can be shown to be FPT using the same ish techniques as for Feedback Vertex Set

Comment: @M.Monet Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Please post this as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: @daniello Nice! In my application, a forest is sufficient, but indeed, a tree is preferred. Your comment and M.Monet's combined is a perfect answer! Thanks.